# How to enable CORS using aws cdk? I keep getting No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I created a lambda and apigateway using aws cdk.
It works fine from postman.

When I make a post call from the browser i get `No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`.

So I am trying to enable CORS in API Gateway, using the CDK.
I am doing it the following way:

```
// users microservice api gateway
    const apiGateway = new LambdaRestApi(this, "usersApi", {
      restApiName: "Users Service",
      handler: microServices.fn,
      proxy: false,
    });

    // creating resources
    const users = apiGateway.root.addResource("users");
    users.addMethod("POST");
    users.addCorsPreflight({
      allowOrigins: ["*"],
      allowHeaders: ["*"],
      allowMethods: ["*"],
    });
```

But I still get `No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"`.
What am I missing? How do I enable CORS via the cdk?

Comment: Any news on this? Experiencing the same problem.

Comment: See `Enabling CORS support for Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations` section - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html. The lambda handler is responsible for the CORS headers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your lambda has to put CORS headers in its response.

For example:

```
return {
    isBase64Encoded: false,
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('success'),
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST',
    }
}
```

reference - see `Enabling CORS support for Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations` section

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: Nope. The CORS response should come from an OPTIONS request, not a POST request. You configure API Gateway to respond to the OPTIONS request, you don't handle that in Lambda.

Comment: Hm, this is what I did in my setup and it seemed to work. OP already enabled it in API gateway as specified in the question - so what's the solution here?

Comment: I see your point @gshpychka.
May I ask what the "isBase64Encoded: false," for?

Comment: To designate that the response body is not encoded with base64.